# Using different package declarations in .java classes than their real file system locations, in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently developing a code generator, and I have built a test suite for it. The general ideia of how it is organized is depicted in the following image:

[image]

The `Tests.java` is a standard `JUnit` test class. I expect it to be on

```
package tests.system.bytecode.temp_tests;
```

as any Java developer would expect.

On the other hand, `IOrderable.java` and `TreeSet.java` are to be used by my code generator (after they are compiled to .class files, that is). But it is a bit troublesome for me to manage their current big big package declarations. The situation will only get worse as I add more tests and start to try to organize(nest) even more the tests.

It'd be perfect if `IOrderable.java` and `TreeSet.java` could have package declarations independent of their real paths, far removing future maintenance problems.

Is it possible to accomplish this with Eclipse? Maybe using Ant or Maven?

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: Compiling .java classes in my Eclipse project with package declarations that don't correspond to their physical path in the project.

Comment: I mean, what would be the problem when you put the files where they actually belong according to standard conventions?

Comment: Really big package declarations both in the .java files as in the other kinds of files that will go on with them. If I later decide to, for example, change the name of test from temp_tests to abc_tests I'll have to manually edit a lot of other files I'm not currently showing here. Even worse, trying to move temp_tests to any other folder will also make me have to change things.

Comment: That's true, but any IDE will do that for you.

Comment: It won't do for my other non-java files. Plus, it is a pain in the ass to have to look to my generated code with reaaaaaaaaaally big package names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4160/discussion-between-michael667-and-devoured-elysium)

Answer (score 2):

> Compiling .java classes in my Eclipse project with package declarations that don't correspond to their physical path in the project.

Should be not possible.

---

But you can separete the classes by different source folders.

In Eclipse you can have several source folders. When compiling they get mixed, so it would be what you need: one `src` folder for the normal classes and one `src-gen` Folder for the generated classes.

And with maven you can do the same.

There you have by default:

- `src/main/java`
- `src/test/java`

But you can add for example `src/main/java2` or `target/generated-src`

Therefore you need the `org.codehaus.mojo` `build-helper-maven-plugin`. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/target/generated-src</source>
                 </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hmm I see. But I'd like to have all the files of a given test in the same folder, it will be a PITA to have to be always switching between 2 folders when developing/maintaining a given test :(

Comment: @devoured elysium: depends on how you work, I always use F3, and CTRL+Shift+T to open a class, so the different root folders should be no problem.

Comment: I also use it, too. But inside each folder my test class is always called *Tests*, so CTRL SHIFT T is worthless there.

Comment: @devoured elysium: I get it, in this case you need to have different names of course.